# Parsing empty json array as null object with GSON

Tags: java, json, rest, gson

I am working with some not really well designed APIs and when the object is null it returns empty array, like this:

No-null response:

```
"SourceType": {
  "ID": "2",
  "NameCZ": "Pokyny",
  "NameEN": "Information"
},
```

Null response:

```
"SourceType": [],
```

Is there a way to parse the null response as null object with GSON? Because when I try to simple parse it to POJO it obviously throws `Expected BEGIN_OBJECT but was BEGIN_ARRAY` error when there is this kind of null response.

Comment: _Is there a way to parse the null response as null object with GSON?_ Why not? But nothing is for free: consider implementing type adapters (+ factories for better flexibility) to deal with the bad design choices, and possibly using `@JsonAdapter` in order to specify badly designed fields like `SourceType` to narrow down the scope of the type adapters.

Comment: Sure about the error message? For me it indicates the other way around, there is a { where a [ is expected

Comment: @Turo You seem to have swapped the same. :) The OP seems to have declared the `SourceType` field type as an array or a collection, thus having problem deserializing a "normal" value, not null. I would suggest the OP not to declare the field as an array or a collection, but annotate the field with `@JsonAdatper(EmptyArrayToNullTypeAdapterFactory.class)` where `EmptyArrayToNullTypeAdapterFactory` is a custom type adapter factory producing a type adapter that is able to coerce JSON empty arrays `[]` to Java `null` to deal with the weird API.

Comment: Yes, I was experimenting with declaring SourceType as an array and I copied wrong error message by mistake (: I will try to solve it with the TypeAdapter, I didn't know about these advance features, that GSON has. Thank you for your advice!

Comment: meet the same issue, PHP will give out the empty array when object is null

Answer (score -1):

As far as I know there isn't. I think you should ask them to change the service structure. If you want, you can compare the http service response code returned in an empty state with the http service response code returned in a full state. if this is different, you can parse accordingly.

Comment: Http response code will be the same for all cases, because this is just a part of the json from the request